# How to change RadioButtonList Name

Tags: javascript

This my HTML:

```
<table id="WizardSRS_rb_list" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="WizardSRS_rb_list_1" type="radio" value="No" name="WizardSRS:rb_list">
<label for="WizardSRS_rb_list_1">No</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I can get to

```
<input id="WizardSRS_rb_list_1" type="radio" value="No" name="WizardSRS:rb_list">
```

and change the value but the

`<label for="WizardSRS_rb_list_1">No</label>`

still showing "No" and this is normal,because i need to change text in the

`<label for="WizardSRS_rb_list_1">No</label>`

but how cat i do this?in first it easy to get $("#ID") but how to get to this `for="WizardSRS"` object?

Comment: have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: It looks like youre using jQuery, if so try $('label[for="WizardSRS_rb_list_1"]').text("Desired text");

Comment: Thx !!!@ Beamer180 it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
$('#WizardSRS_rb_list_1').next().html('No')
```

or use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('label[for="WizardSRS_rb_list_1"]').html('no')
```

Answer (score 1):

**In jQuery:**

```
$( "<label for='WizardSRS_rb_list_1'>No</label>" ).appendTo( "body" );
$( "<label for='SOMETHING_ELSE_rb_list_1'>YES</label>" ).appendTo( "body" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do do what Arun suggested above or for faster access, just give `label` and `id' and access using that.